# How do i get out of boot loop?

Tags: dual-boot, plymouth

The purple screen with the Ubuntu logo and orange dogs are all I can access. My computer froze except the mouse while I was using linux, then i shut it down. It froze I think in recovery journal, I shut it down now it only gives me that purple screen with orange dots. I'm also on a duelboot, with Windows 10. It was working fine earlier today, so how do I fix my ubuntu?

Comment: Could someone add a boot loop Tag? I tried to categorize best I could

Comment: Try installing `xserver-xorg-input-all`

Answer (score 0):

okay, a third reset weaker to fix the problem. Sorry about that, Linux novice who knows vary little regarding terminal.

Comment: Install the Sysinfo application from the default Ubuntu repositories and check if all your computer's hardware resources are recognized by the system.